# Custom View-Based NSOutlineView disclosure?

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion, nsoutlineview

Is there a simple way to customize the disclosure triangle for expandable items?

I tried removing it and calling `[outlineView expandItem:X]` when my custom disclosure indicator was clicked, but all the sexy built-in animations didn't work. Is there a trick to enable those animations? I tried `[outlineView beginUpdates]` but that yielded no results either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the animator:

```
[[[outlineView] animator] expandItem:xyz]
```

Answer (score -1):

use - (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView willDisplayOutlineCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item;